# Is it true that if a gerund can be replaced by a noun, the 'gerund' in question is not a present participle?

Tags: gerunds

Take this sentence for instance: We began shouting at the top of our lungs for the bus to stop.

Since the phrase in question 'shouting at the top of our lungs for the bus to stop' cannot be replaced with a noun, the mentioned phrase definitely functions as a gerund.

Is this rule correct all the time?

Comment: "Began" is a catenative verb and the subordinate gerund-participial clause "shouting at the top of our lings ..." is its catenative complement. It would not be possible in this instance to replace the clause with a semantically appropriate noun phrase.

Comment: You could rephrase the sentence as— *We began **to shout** at the top of our lungs for the bus to stop.* Insofar as the old rule goes, Gerunds and infinitives are both verbal nouns, and so there's no question of a participle here. You might have guessed it from the fact that _You do/begin [something]_ , and so it has to be a Noun Equivalent.

Comment: @user405662 Yes, but "shouting" and "shout" are verbs, not nouns. In any case, clauses are not nouns. Note that the classification of subordinate clauses is based on their internal form rather than spurious analogies with the parts of speech.

Comment: A bit of the traditional stuff— *I bid him go* : This would be broken up as— *Subject+ tr.verb+ object of tr.verb+ bare infinitive (functioning as Object complement, i.e., describes the Object).* So as per this logic, *Let's go fishing would be parsed as— Implied  Subject+ tr.verb+ object+ object complement (so, fishing is a noun).* But I know you would say it's a verb for much the same reason.

Comment: @user405662 "Go" doesn't describe the object. Object complements are either adjectives ("I painted my house **white**") or nouns ("They elected him **treasurer**").  You've completely ignored the fact that "I bid him go" and "Let's go fishing" are catenative constructions. You really have to learn modern scholarly grammar.

Comment: @BillJ From your answer, I interpret that *shouting* in the cited sentence functions as a present participle? Therefore, the rule of *a gerund phrase being replaceable by a noun makes it a gerund* is not applicable in every case? 
In this case then, would it be safe to say that one can't go wrong if they analyse the function of a word based on its syntactic context in the sentence--as compared to basing on a general rule?